# Trying to execute jar using cygwin, arguments not recognized

Tags: java, jar, arguments, cygwin

I have a makefile that calls a java parser to process some files before compilation. While in linux works perfectly when I am running that on a Windows 7 machine using cygwin my input are recognized as jar files.

My command inside my make is something like

```
java -jar ${MY_DIR}/myParser.jar -arg1 -arg2 -arg3 input.file output.file ;\
```

and I get an error that input.file is not a valid jar file... I assume it has something to do with my paths and how cygwin handles java but I can't make it work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the complete command after make expands ${MY_DIR}? Windows uses \\ to separate directories but you have a / in the command-line. The windows version of java needs a windows style path to the .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting up ()

```
exec java -jar $(cygpath -w /path/to/myParser.jar) -arg1 -arg2 -arg3  input.file output.file
```

Srry not enough rep to add comment .